# Chest or corpse with three Souvenirs of reprisal

Tags: dark-souls

I am fairly sure somewhere in Dark souls there is a chest or corpse with three souvenirs of reprisal on it. Similar to how you can find 3 sunlight medals in Anor Londo. However I can't remember where I found them. Does anyone know? I searched around but found nothing.

Comment: http://darksouls.wikidot.com/souvenir-of-reprisal

Comment: Wikidot does not have a location for a body with 3 souvenirs. Which is why I am asking the question.

Comment: I know there's a spot where you can pick up 3 Eyes of Death in the Catacombs, but there's nothing like that for Souvenirs of Reprisal.

Comment: I could have sworn there was in the painted world or in Ash lake or somewhere really out of the way. If you really think so, I'd consider it an answer, not one I'd accept yet, but if no one responds for a while I would. I'll be keeping an eye on this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't exist, so far as I have heard or know, and I cannot find it anywhere.